# How do I properly pass an array between methods

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing

I'm having trouble passing an array between methods and have excerpted my code below.

I've successfully created two arrays, `computerDice` and `humanDice`, and now I need to count the number of ones, twos, threes, etc in each array. See example below the code. I've validated that a.) that the input arrays contain valid data and b.) the counter works properly.

However, now I'm trying to return `occurences` as an array--six distinct values of `occurence` representing ones, twos, threes, etc. in the array being SENT to the method--and have been unsuccessful. I keep having issues with my `occurence` return...incompatible types, bad operand typed for operand +...and I get something different with each thing I try. I'm obviously missing something with how to cast/populate this variable.

NOTE: This is homework; I'm just trying to grasp my conceptual mis-steps.

```
// SEND VALUES TO numToFind AND CREATE SCORING ARRAY FOR computerDice AND humanDice
        for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
        {
            int[] pipCountsComputer = findVals(computerDice,i);
            int[] pipCountsHuman = findVals(humanDice,i);
            System.out.println(i + " " + pipCountsComputer + " " + pipCountsHuman);
        }
    }
//
// COUNT INSTANCES OF numToFind IN arr[] AND RETURN THE occurence
    public static int[] findVals(int[] arr, int numToFind)
    {
        int[] occurence=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == numToFind)
                occurence = occurence+1;
        }
        return occurence;
    }
```

I've already validated that, for example, given `computerArray` = `52334` and `humanArray` = `11163` my print statement yields:

`1 0 3`    (ones, computer has 0 ones, human has 3 ones)
`2 1 0`    (twos, computer has 1 two, human has 0 twos)
`3 2 1`     etc.
`4 1 0`    My desired arrays for this dataset would be:
`5 1 0`    `pipCountsComputer{0,1,2,1,1,1}`
`6 0 1`    `pipCountsHuman{3,0,1,0,0,1}`

Comment: `++` is a unary operator for primitive types. An array is not a primitive type.

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make sense. You are counting the number of occurances, which is of course a single number, and you want to return that as an array. What would the array contain?

Comment: The code you've posted wont compile. You're returning `occurrence` but your return type is `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, try this for counting the number of occurrences:

```
public static int findVals(int[] arr, int numToFind) {
    int occurence = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == numToFind)
            occurence++;
    }
    return occurence;
}
```

I really don't understand why you want to return an array, an *occurrence* is just a number.

Answer (score 2):

As this smells like homework, I won't give you the answer but hint to it...

> now I'm trying to return occurences as an array

You have not coded for this yet... look at the method signature again

`public static void findVals(int[] arr, int numToFind)`

Comment: Homework indeed. I was adding the homework tag and disclaimer when this came through. :)  If your hint what that void needed to be changed to int[], I'd already done that. I've also posted my "after" code...(I ~had~ posted my "before" code)...